# Rails test failure 500 when I use .includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm developing a small e-commerce and I´ve a problem when I run the tests for my cart controller.

here cart controller

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart #modul current_cart in controllers/concerns
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_action :set_current_cart, only: [:index] 

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    end
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to catalog_index_url, notice: 'Cart was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.includes(line_items: :product).find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def cart_params
    params.fetch(:cart, {})
  end
end
```

and here my tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CartsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @line_item = line_items(:one)
    @product = products(:one)
    @cart = carts(:one)

  end

  test "should get index" do

    get carts_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_cart_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create cart" do
    assert_difference('Cart.count') do
      post carts_url, params: { cart: {} }
    end

    assert_redirected_to cart_url(Cart.last)
  end

  test "should show cart" do
    get cart_url(@cart)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_cart_url(@cart)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update cart" do
    patch cart_url(@cart), params: { cart: {} }
    assert_redirected_to cart_url(@cart)
  end

  test "should destroy cart" do
    post line_items_url, params: { product_id: products(:one).id }
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    assert_difference('Cart.count', -1) do
      delete cart_url(@cart)
    end
    assert_redirected_to catalog_index_url
  end
end
```

here the results:

> Failure: CartsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_cart  Expected
>   response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <500: Internal Server
>   Error>
>
> Failure: CartsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit  Expected response
>   to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
>
> Failure: CartsControllerTest#test_should_update_cart  Expected
>   response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <500: Internal Server
>   Error>

here is the modul current cart for the cartsController:

```
module CurrentCart

  private

  def set_current_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

I think that the problem is here:
if I remove this in the method set_cart from the cart controller: .includes(line_items: :product) the tests will run perfectly without failure, but I cannot understand why.
(I put the include because otherwise I get this error when I access the cart from the browser:

> USE eager loading detected   LineItem => [:product]   Add to your
>   finder: :includes => [:product] Call stack

UPDATE:

I found something interesting in the file "test.log" :

```
Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError - user: claudio
DELETE /carts/980190963
AVOID eager loading detected
  LineItem => [:product]
  Remove from your finder: :includes => [:product]
Call stack
  ##here there's a path##.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CartsControllerTest>'
  ##here there's a path##:in `block in <class:CartsControllerTest>'
```

Comment: How do you models look? Put a `binding.pry` right before `Cart.includes(line_items: :product).find(params[:id])` and run it manually in the console. What do you get?

Comment: Do you get a larger error trace when you run the tests? If so, it would be great if you could pop that in your question to help identify the source. One simple thing to try: run `rails db:test:prepare`. It could be your `includes` is looking at tables not available to the test env.

Comment: @SRack : no, the error trace is just that.. I´ve tried with rails db:test:prepare but its the same, nothing change. There's a way to see why it gives the <500: Internal Server Error>  ??

Comment: Yep, go with @DennyMueller's approach - use a debugger like [Pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) and run the line. That way you'll get a full trace that will give an idea what's going on. Give that a shot and update the answer if the trace if you're still stuck (feel free to @ me when you've done that).   Hope it helps!

Comment: @SRack I'm sorry. I've been watching all the day tutorial about binding.pry but I can not understand what I´ve exactly to do to find the source of <500: Internal Server Error>.. I´ve navigate with "step" or "next" to try to find something but its just impossible to understand.. some advice? -> I´ve update the topic with something I found in the test.log, maybe its helpful.

Comment: @Mardok Put a binding.pry right before `Cart.includes(line_items: :product).find(params[:id])` and run that line manually in the console. What do you get?